# I can always get balance even if the metamask account is logged-out

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

```
<head>
        <title>Test ethereum metamask</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="module">
            import { ethers } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/5.7.2/ethers.esm.js";
            const provider = ((window.ethereum != null) ? new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum) : ethers.providers.getDefaultProvider());
            const balanceObj = await provider.getBalance("0xE0552897c6495D7efb98F3823cd48bf19e703D0b");
            console.log("========== balance object =", balanceObj);
            let balance = balanceObj._hex;
            console.log("========== balance hexa =", balance);
            balance = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
            console.log("========== balance =", balance);
            document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = balance;
        </script>
    </head>
```

Even if the metamask account is disconnected after I run the app then I can get the balance, although I should get `undefined` when calling `console.log("========== balance hexa =", balance);`

So how to deal with Metamask connexion ?

Comment: You have the address hard coded so there is no need to connect a wallet. The blockchain is all public.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple types of method in a smart contract. A viewable method doesnt need any authentication, hence you are getting it.

You can check this sample erc20 for multiple types [here](https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea).

You can also try executing the read / view type methods without connecting your metamask.